# Buildozer not installing Android SDK

Tags: python, kivy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildozer

I have a problem building an android application with Python Kivy, Buildozer. Buildozer isn't downloading and installing the Android SDK Platform and it shows this error:

`# sdkmanager path "/home/sergij/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager" does not exist, sdkmanager is notinstalled`

There is no folder named `android-sdk` in the `/.buildozer/android/platform/` folder. I tried deleting the `.buildozer` folder and tried again but it didn't work.

I'm using WSL 2 with Ubuntu 20.04, and I was trying to run this command:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by finding out the $HOME/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk has a zip file, then i just unziped it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to just use sudo and get the final part to continue. My issue was I had no java runtime. Went to java.com got the latest jre and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain how your problem and the solution relates to the problem here in discussion, and how your solution will help.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Note: This answer was previously embedded in the question by the OP. I have moved it to this answer so that it can be evaluated separately from the other proposed answers.*</sub>

To fix this problem just run `buildozer` as root. You can do that by running:

```
sudo buildozer android debug deploy run
```